# How can I remove the lines around the edge of an object?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I got a Minecraft rig which I want to have as a transparent image for a thumbnail. I always get these weird lines around the head (and sometimes on the rest of the rig as well), but I want to get rid of them as they don't look nice. I tried removing the lines in Photoshop, but that takes a lot of time.

Please have a look at the screenshot which has been attached to this post. How do I get rid of the lines around my Blender Minecraft rig? I'm a Blender beginner, so please send very clear and detailed instructions if you know the answer! :)

Thanks!

Problem occurs with:
- Windows 7 Pro 32-bits
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bits
- Blender 2.75a (also had the problem in previous versions)

Download link for .blend file:
https://mega.nz/#!LV4zAJ6a!SYgFytB9C92YXd5gNaH8C7m2fWys2e0AetcRpmFeTwc

[image: The white and colored lines around the head of the Minecraft rig are what I want to get rid of.]

Comment: Is it possible to see the .blend file?! I assume that your edges are not correctly align/ that you have doubles (doubled vertices laying on top of each other)

Comment: Hey, I just added a download link for the .blend file to the post :)

Comment: Please pack your textures! Textures are not saved with the blend file unless you pack them. Use File->External_Data->Pack_all_into_.blend and re-upload your file

Comment: Thanks, I changed the URL so now it should be saved correctly and you can download it :)

Comment: I get an error when I try to download your .blend file. Please upload it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a UV layout problem - not enough margin between the UV islands, so color data is bleeding over. From what I can see of the UV texture on the right everything is just packed way to closely together. But maybe you can fix this by scaling the UV islands in a little, one-by-one.

### Instead of this...

[image: A UV layout with no margin between the islands]

### More like this:

[image: A UV layout with some margin between the islands]

Also, to fix triangles like that one on the arm, enable Auto Smooth in the Mesh Context.

[image: Enabling Auto Smooth]

### Update:

I looked at your .blend and it does appear that the UV layout is the problem.

Note how there is no margin between the islands.

[image: Minecraft character UV layout]

In addition to that, there are parts of the layout that are doubled-up. This may or may not be intentional, but it means a texture in that region will show up on more than one place on the mesh.

Comment: could also be an issue with non premultiplied textures... without the file is hard to guess.

Comment: Hey, I just added a download link for the .blend file to the post :)

Comment: If you can fix the problem (and if you want to), can you send me the .blend file? :)